# mapbox API : how can I set a fallback for the 'get' expression?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-expressions

I use this expression to set the *line-color* of a layer.

```
map.addLayer({
  ...
  'paint': {
    'line-color': ['get', 'color'],
  },
  ...
})
```

But what if the color attribute is not defined ? Is there a way to set a fallback value ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily do this with the `coalesce` expression ([docs here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#coalesce)), which will always resolve to the first non-null value in the provided list of values.

In your example, this would something like:

```js
map.addLayer({
  ...
  'paint': {
    'line-color': ['coalesce', ['get', 'color'], '#00ffff']
  },
  ...
})
```

There's a more involved example of this expression being used to determine an icon fallback [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fallback-image/).

---

⚠️ disclaimer: I currently work at Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: thanks !   PS working at Mapbox is not a problem here I think :)